# Silverlight with RIA services on IIS 10.0 results in 404 error

Tags: iis, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services, windows-server

Trying to migrate an existing working Silverlight application with WCF RIA services from **IIS 6.0** to **IIS 10.0** on W**indows Server 2016** but the application fails returning **404 error**s. When I install Visual Studio on the server and try running the application then it works fine within the context of IIS Express.

The server has the following components installed.

- Microsoft Silverlight 5.0
- Microsoft Silverlight 4 SDK
- Microsoft Silverlight 5 SDK
- WCF RIA Services V1.0 SP2

I’ve even tried to directly access the virtual RIA services created by the `System.ServiceModel.DomainServices` and it results in 404 errors as well. The below is the screen print from fiddler when directly browsing from IIS. What am I missing here? Has anyone successfully deployed Silverlight with RIA services on IIS 10.0 ?

[image]

Per the comments, attached is the actual error when accessing the URL from the browser and the web.config settings

[image]
[image]

Appreciate your help on this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After long struggle figured out that we may need to enable `HTTP Activation`
for the `WCF Services` under `Add Roles and Features Wizard` as shown in the image. The **404** error thrown by WCF RIA services is really vague and may not give you the actual error even in tools like Fiddler.

Please note, I'm using Windows Server 2016, you may see a bit different wizard depending on the server version you're using.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Dennis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46921509/81595) worked for me. For anyone that would like to use Powershell to perform the installation, this is the command that I used.

```
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName WCF-HTTP-Activation45 -All;
```

Note that my first attempt failed because there were parent features which were missing. The `-All` switch ensured that they were installed too.